# "Return" button on Android and iOS decreases value of input type="number"

Tags: android, ios, angular, input, submit-button

I`m writing simple component on Angular. Basically this is input with two separate buttons (one for increasing other for decreasing number in input).
Everything works fine, but my QA said that on mobile devices: Andriod and iOS "submit" button which supposedly have to close keyboard decreases value of input by 1 instead.
I was surfing the internet for two days now but, couldn't find at least any hint.
This is my HTML:

```
  <button class="btn-counter minus" (click)="reduceItemCount()">
    <span class="icon icon-minus"></span>
  </button>
  <label class="quantity-counter-wrapper">
    <input class="input-quantity-counter"[formControl]="inputControl" type="number"
      onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 190 && event.keyCode !== 110" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
  </label>
  <button class="btn-counter plus" (click)="increaseItemCount()">
    <span class="icon icon-plus"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

And this is cy component:

```
import {
  Component, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Output,
} from '@angular/core';

import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * Quantity selector component
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'amer-quantity-selector',
  templateUrl: './quantity-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quantity-selector.component.scss'],
})

export class QuantitySelectorComponent implements OnInit {
  /**
   * Form from parent element
   */
  @Input()
  parentForm: FormGroup;

  /**
   * Control name to recognize which FormControl to get from parentForm
   */
  @Input()
  controlName: string;

  /**
   * Number by which we should increase or reduce number in input
   */
  @Input()
  inputStep = 1;

  /**
   * Minimum value allowed
   */
  @Input()
  minValue = 0;

  /**
   * Maximum value allowed
   */
  @Input()
  maxValue = 999;

  inputControl: FormControl;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inputControl = this.parentForm.get(this.controlName) as FormControl;

    this.inputControl.valueChanges.subscribe((val: any) => {
      /**
       * Clear non digital symbols
       */
      this.inputControl.setValue(parseInt(this.inputControl.value, 10), { emitEvent: false });

      /**
      * Set value to minimum allowed if user enters lower number
      */
      if (val < this.minValue || Number.isNaN(val) || val === null) {
        this.inputControl.setValue(this.minValue);
      }

      /**
      * Set value to maximum allowed if user enters higher number
      */
      if (val > this.maxValue) {
        this.inputControl.setValue(this.maxValue);
      }
    });
  }

  /**
 * Increase quantity counter by "inputStep"
 */
  increaseItemCount(): void {
    this.inputControl.setValue(parseInt(this.inputControl.value, 10) + this.inputStep);
  }

  /**
 * Descrease quantity counter by "inputStep"
 */
  reduceItemCount(): void {
    this.inputControl.setValue(parseInt(this.inputControl.value, 10) - this.inputStep);
  }
}
```

Comment: Add `type="button"` to all the buttons that they are not submit (Angular, by defect consider all the buttons as submit)

Comment: TY very much!
Hope this helps.
Tell you when it is tested)